# Where is Flask's GUI?

Tags: python, flask

I have installed Flask on Windows using pip. I think Flask is a framework. I have tried many times to find its GUI but I am not able to find it. Is it because there is no GUI framework for Flask?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. The only sort of GUI I could think of in this context would be the web pages that are sent to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Flask doesn't have a GUI. It is a framework, which in this case means it's just a collection of modules. It isn't an app and it isn't a website, it's just code.

Answer (score 0):

Flask uses [Jinja2](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/) templates out of the box.  They're straightforward to set up, but the documentation on Flask's website is barebones.

You'll want to reference the [official Jinja2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/) for any further clarification on what the syntax should be.